# How to extract a specific text from text file in c#

Tags: c#, io

[image]Basically I have a text file in which there is a title and description. I want to extract the title in a specific text box and all the description in other.
I have tried this code:

```
protected void FillForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputString;
    textBoxContents.Text = "";
    using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(@"E:\file.txt"))
    {
        inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();

        while (inputString != null)
        {
            textBoxContents.Text += inputString + "<br />";
            inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

What I get is the all content of file but I want a chunk of text to appear in the textbox from this file.

Comment: Which part do you want to extract? Where do you find the title and the description? Can you provide a small sample?

Comment: As far as first questions go, its pretty good formatting and follows guidelines pretty well.. I'm still a little unsure of what your problem is though, you do get the first line and then put it into contents, but then you put all the other lines in here as well? Do you not just need to set the text of a textbox before the while loop?

Comment: Your question reads like this: _"Dear SO, help me decode my bespoke file format. I will provide no sample and will not describe the format"_. We need a sample file!

Comment: You really should give us a sample of what the text file looks like (including the data you need to extract). Like the police department that had their toilets stolen, we've nothing to go on . . .

Comment: i have attached an image. Anticipatory thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to find the first line and and split it there:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\file.txt");

int positionOfFirstLineEnd = text.IndexOf('\n');

string title = text.Substring(0, positionOfFirstLineEnd);
string description = text.Substring(positionOfFirstLineEnd + 1);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but the line number in which description is can be changed according to scenario so i need to extract description by matching the words or something like that

Comment: What do you expect to see according to your text in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a text file in which there is a title and description....

Seems like a description of the file format to me ;)

I am assuming from your code that the title is the first line of the text file. If this is the case, it appears that you are missing two steps:

1. You need to assign the value from the first read to the text box you want the title in.
2. You then need to set the value of *inputString* to an empty string or use another variable to hold the read of the body text. This ensures you do not duplicate the title text in the body.

```
protected void FillForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string inputString;
    textBoxContents.Text = "";
    using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(@"E:\file.txt"))
    {
        inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();


        //assign inputString value to title text box
        //set inputString value to ""


        while (inputString != null)
        {
            textBoxContents.Text += inputString + "<br />";
            inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> How to extract a specific text from text file

What is *specific*? It is the most important thing to know. Knowing what makes that text *specific* is the thing, which allow you to write a peace of code what will do the right job.

Typically, there are:

- Line, containing (starting from, ending with) specific characters and variants (line before that, line after that, text in line before that, etc).
- Line number N.
- Something else (tell us).

Knowing that your code is almost correct:

```
protected void FillForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxContents.Text = "";
    using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(@"E:\file.txt"))
    {
        string inputString = null;
        int lineNumber;
        do
        {
            inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
            lineNumber++;
            // this
            // get line number 7
            if(lineNumber == 7)
            {
                 textBoxContents.Text += inputString + "<br />";
                 break;
            }
            // or perhaps this
            // get next line after line containing "Description"
            if(inputString.Contains("Description"))
            {
                 inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                 textBoxContents.Text += inputString + "<br />";
                 break;
            }
        } while (inputString != null)
    }
}
```

P.S.: a tip, don't make event handler a *method*. That means

```
void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillForm();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip 
you are close to my problem. Actually there can be any words in the description so i just need to get that string. you can see the image of text file i have added now

Comment: That image doesn't answer on question how this description can be determined. Imagine a wall of text, I want some word from there, can you solve it? Nope. You need clear criteria of how description can be found in your text to *find* it. As a human it maybe obvious for you to find some text, but you want a code to do so, then *specify* please, how code can find it and then, more likely, it's a trivial task, answered on SO many times already.